# Problems mounting kerberos protected NFS share from a client machine

Tags: nfs, kerberos

I have a client Linux (Fedora 16) PC that I want to use to access a NFS share. Running the command

```
mount -v -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 server.company.com:/home/share/username /media/nfs
```

results in

```
access denied by server while mounting server.company.com:/home/share/username
```

This error message is not particularly helpful, as it seems to be some kind of catch all response when something goes wrong (which makes most of the Google results for this irrelevant).

A lot of the documentation relating the Kerberos and NFS refers to a keytab file, which seems to only be suitable for clients with fixed hostnames or IP addresses. Also, if my understanding of a keytab file is correct, it is only useful for connecting to a protected resource without entering any usernames or passwords, and I am quite happy to authenticate each time I need to mount the resource.

My client is just a simple Fedora 16 installation that has not special privileges on the network. I also do not have any administrative privileges on the server hosting the NFS shares, so I can't see any server settings or log files. I do however have Kerberos credentials, and I can successfully obtain a Kerberos ticket with kinit.

I know my credentials are correct, because I can run kinit. I know the share exists, because I can SFTP into it with an application like Filezilla. So what am I missing with the mount command?